# How to upload particular desktop folder file on to server in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have plan to develop a web application in java. I want these thing-
 First i have to create a folder on desktop and inside this folder suppose i create 5 more folders with the name of A,B,C,D,E.now i want,if i add some text or image document on folder A. then only the person
login through username A and password(some password) can access this particular file. and same things with other folders. i mean if admin create 5 user's with the name of A,B,C,D,E.and each user can access and  download  it's particular files.

and if admin put some new file in folder in A then when user A login through web application he can access only newly add files from folder A.

sir this thing i want to do but how to initiate i do not know.
please help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to provide the root folder's path in web.xml, so that your servlet can access it. The Folder should be outside the installation folder of Server

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>CreateFolder</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>pckg.CreateFolder</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<context-param>
        <param-name>ParentFolder</param-name>
        <param-value>/z/y/x/users</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
        <param-name>FileName</param-name>
        <param-value>xyz.png</param-value>
</context-param>
```

CreateFolder Servlet :-

```
private String userFolder;

public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    userFolder= getServletContext().getInitParameter("ParentFolder");
}

public doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException){

     String userName = request.getParameter("UserName");
     String location=""


          if(userName != null){
              location +="/"+userName;
               if (!location .exists()) {
                 location .mkdirs(); //If does not exists then create folder
                }
       }

 }
```

UploadFile Servlet :-

```
private String userFolder;
private String fileName;
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    userFolder= getServletContext().getInitParameter("ParentFolder");
    fileName= getServletContext().getInitParameter("FileName");
}

public doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException){

     String userName = request.getParameter("UserName");
     String location=""


          if(userName != null){
              location +="/"+userName;
               if (!location .exists()) {
                   UploadeFile(location );
                }
       }

 }


 private void UploadeFile(String location ){

    String file = location+"/"+fileName;
    //Code to upload the file

    MoveFile(file);//Move to different location
  }
```

First get the `UserName` after proper validation. Read Folder path from `web.xml`. 
Append the `UserName` to the folder path, check if path exists or not.
If path does not exists then create the Path.

While uploading the file to user. After successful completion of upload, move the file to different location. Hence, next time the user logins into the system he will only see the new Documents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You just send which folder u want to download and file name. if you can get path from session its give more secure you have login id for user you create it. if you upload new data you delete the folder and create new.that time you have only one latest data.may i think its help for you

```html
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");       
        String path = request.getParameter("folder");
        String name = request.getParameter("filename");
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        String filepath = "Your path" + path + "/" + name, filename = name;
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        response.addHeader("content-disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        int octet;
        while ((octet = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(octet);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
```

Comment: tnx for ur reply. but only i have to access newly added file with out any delete .